# To determine no beating cardiomyocytes from ECG or video recording

Tags: cardiology, signal-processing

I am trying to find data and some method by which I can see and say that there are some cardiomyocytes not working.
I have reviewed many arrythmia data where I think I can see much cardiomyocetes there and there which are not beating at all.

**Is there any method with available data for the recognisition of cardiomyocytes without beating?**

I am particularly interested in the paediatric data.
I am using at the moment ECG data after cardiac infarction.

**What is the name of this video record?**
Picture from House season 3 episode 2:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of cardiomyocytes is lost during an infarction. Instead, fibrous tissue forms, but it only preserves structural integrity, having no contractile function <sup>[1]</sup>. Myocardial infarction is an uncommon condition in pediatrics, happening very rare, when embolization occurs due to blood coagulation affections or heart congenital defects <sup>[2]</sup>.

The fibrous tissue has different properties, thus modifying:

- MDE-MRI images <sup>[3]</sup>
- ECG: deep Q wave <sup>[4]</sup>
- echocardiography: hypoechoic and hyperdense echoes inside the fibrotic material (the latter compatible with calcium) <sup>[5]</sup>

That video record is probably about 3D Echocardiography (look [here](http://www.escardio.org/communities/EACVI/CasePortal/Pages/multiplanar--3d-echocardiographic-analysis-of--a-subaortic-membrane.aspx) at Video 2 and figure 2).

References:

1. Yao Sun, [*Myocardial repair/remodelling following infarction: roles of local factors*](http://cardiovascres.oxfordjournals.org/content/81/3/482.full.pdf)
2. Nicola Carano *et al.*, [*Acute Myocardial Infarction in a Child: Possible Pathogenic Role of Patent Foramen Ovale Associated With Heritable Thrombophilia*](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/114/2/e255.full)
3. Harikrishna Tandri *et al.*, [*Noninvasive detection of myocardial fibrosis in arrhythmogenic right ventricular cardiomyopathy using delayed-enhancement magnetic resonance imaging*](http://content.onlinejacc.org/article.aspx?articleid=1136198)
4. ECGpedia - [Pathologic Q Waves](http://en.ecgpedia.org/wiki/Pathologic_Q_Waves)
5. Berenzstein CS *et al.*, [*Usefulness of echocardiography and doppler echocardiography in endomyocardial fibrosis*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10804436)

Comment: The video in House series is probably fake. I cannot understand from which angle you can get so circular picture. Those real-life pictures are much more challenging than the one in House.

Comment: @Masi I could't understand that either.